# Twitter - media error while uploading image using upload.json

Tags: javascript, twitter

```
 getMediaBinary: function() {
    var file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0],
        reader = new FileReader(),
        deferred = $.Deferred();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        return deferred.resolve(reader.result);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    return deferred.promise();
},
getMediaData: function() {
    var file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0],
        reader = new FileReader(),
        deferred = $.Deferred();

    reader.onloadend = function () {

        return deferred.resolve(reader.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
},
uploadMedia: function() {
  var formData = new FormData();

    $.when(JTWEET.getMediaBinary(), JTWEET.getMediaData() ).then(function(media, media_data) {
        formData.append('media', media);
        formData.append('media_data', media_data);
        return $.ajax({
            url: JTWEET.routerUrl + 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json',
            type: 'POST',
            //   data: { media: document.getElementById('photo').files[0].name, media_data: JTWEET.getMediaData() },
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {
                console.dir(arguments);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.dir(arguments);
            }
        });
    });

},
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":38,"message":"media parameter is missing."}]}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this one out - https://twittercommunity.com/t/post-media-upload-json-always-returns-media-parameter-is-missing/27962

> Figured it out finally. Two things are important here:
>   1. the parameter name has to be “media”, not “media[]”
>   2. Do not set the contentType property. It prevents a Content-Type header with the correct boundary value from being automatically created.
>
> A correct options object looks like this:
>
> ```
> var options = {
>     "oAuthServiceName":"twitter",
>     "oAuthUseToken":"always",
>     method: "POST",
>     payload: { "media" : imageblob }
> };
> ```

Comment: how did you create the imageblob?

Comment: I didn't, this is someone else's work.  He has the full code listed [here](https://script.google.com/d/11dB74uW9VLpgvy1Ax3eBZ8J7as0ZrGtx4BPw7RKK-JQXyAJHBx98pY-7/edit?usp=sharing) - you are probably interested most in twitter.gs line 198, `OAuth.prototype.uploadMedia = function(imageblob)` etc.